# what does $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{10} \min(i,j)$ mean

Tags: summation, notation

what does

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}  \sum\limits_{j=1}^{10} \min(i,j)$$

mean?

I'm aware that $\sum$ represents the summation, and min the minimum value . But when written like $\sum \sum$ , what exactly does it mean?

Comment: Hi. Is it less confusing with parentheses? You can read it as: $$\sum_{i=1}^{10}  \left( \sum_{j=1}^{10} \left( \min(i,j) \right) \right) = \left( \sum_{j=1}^{10} \left( \min(1,j) \right) \right)  +  \left( \sum_{j=1}^{10} \left( \min(2,j) \right) \right)  + ... +  \left( \sum_{j=1}^{10} \left( \min(10,j) \right) \right) $$

Comment: Ah,OK. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a *double summation*. Since the summations are all finite, you can read it as either
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}  \left( \sum_{j=1}^{10} \left( \min(i,j) \right) \right)$$
or
$$\sum_{j=1}^{10} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{10} \left( \min(i,j) \right) \right)$$
or even as (if you prefer)
$$\sum_{i,j=0}^{10}\min(i,j)$$
which some people are more accustomed to.

Basically, it is the sum of $\min(i,j)$ for $i,j$ ranging over $[0,10]$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Evaluating the expression $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^{10}\sum_\limits{j=1}^{10}\min(i,j)\ $ is facilitated by dividing the inner sum into two parts:
\begin{align}
\sum_\limits{j=1}^{10}\min(i,j)&=\sum_{j=1}^ij+\sum_{j=i+1}^{10}i\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^ij+(10-i)i\\
&=\frac{i(i+1)}{2}+(10-i)i\
\end{align}
for $\ 1\le i\le9\ $, because $\ \min(i,j)=j\ $ when $\ j\le i\ $ and  $\ \min(i,j)=i\ $ when $\ j>i\ $, and
\begin{align}
\sum_\limits{j=1}^{10}\min(10,j)&=\sum_\limits{j=1}^{10}j\\
&=45
\end{align}
because $\ \min(10,j)=j\ $ whenever $\ 1\le j\le10\ $.